# The type or namespace name 'DP' could not be found 

Tags: 2007

I customized the fab 40 Absence Request template.

I added custom workflows with custom activities (spdactivities, http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/)

works beautifully in dev. Want to move to production.

save site as a template (with content so I can modift the workflows as needed)

get no errors for 'check workflow' but get this when I click Finish:

“(0, 10) The type or namespace name 'DP' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))”

My first instinct is to redeploy sdpactivities in production.

Anything else I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have referenced dll in either GAC or bin folder. It seems you are missing any dll reference. Try to locate error in either EventViewer or SharePoint logs.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check

- Installation in the GAC per ashish's post (must be installed in the GAC)
- Ensure its been installed and the feature activated in your web application

Also check to see if your web.config (for the web app) has the following safecontrols registered

```
<SafeControl Assembly="DP.Sharepoint.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0298457208daed83" Namespace="DP.Sharepoint.Workflow.InfoPath" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="DP.Sharepoint.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0298457208daed83" Namespace="DP.Sharepoint.Workflow.Install" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="DP.Sharepoint.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0298457208daed83" Namespace="DP.Sharepoint.Workflow" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

Comment: THanks so much! ends up it was installed but not activated in production! thanks